# How to view underlying data

Tags: python, python-2.7

Please bear with me regarding the following problem, all in Python.

Say you had a function called filter and this filter function takes in some data and returns back filter options based off of the data. Say that the data is a list of 10 values.

The problem is that when the filter takes data[:4], it will work off of those four values...how should the filter function be set up, or incorporate, ways as to have it filter off of the entire data list, rather than just what was given to it, assume it was given data[:4]

Sorry for the more abstractness of this question, I'll try to work on some sample code to make this clearer.

Comment: Pass the whole data instead, how can you expect filter to somehow guess the rest of the data?

Comment: Not guess...but to base its filter regardless of the subset of data it was given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not possible without fundamentally violating the language.

When a function is passed a subset of the list, all that it knows about are those items. The only way around that is through writing a custom extension of the language which changes its very structure to violate encapsulation ([would it still be Python?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ship_of_Theseus)).

Comment: So there wouldn't be a way to make a function such that it looks at the entire list regardless of the subset of data it was given?

Comment: See comment from Ashwini Chaudhary above. That is probably the only/right way to do it

Comment: @algebr:  Functions only know what you tell them.  You'd have to tell it what's coming into its world.